# How to stop timer in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, timer

In my application i want use `CountDownTimer` and for this i write below codes, but i want after some condition cancel this timer and then not run this timer!

I write below codes and cancel it, but every 1 second again run this timer!

I want after call timer.cancel , this timer has canceled and not run again!

**My Codes:**

```
    private fun startTimer(timer: Long) {
        calTimeChecker = timer
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                //Calculate time
                calTimeChecker -= 1
                var seconds = (calTimeChecker)
                val hours = seconds / (60 * 60)
                val tempMint = seconds - hours * 60 * 60
                val minutes = tempMint / 60
                seconds = tempMint - minutes * 60
                //This call api with MVP
                presenter.getLastInfo(token, auctionId)
            override fun onFinish() {
                footerCheckingLay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                auctionDetail_footerInfo.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                auctionDetail_footerBottom.enableDisableView(false)
                auctionDetail_footerPlusBidBtn.enableDisableView(false)
            }
        }.start()

    override fun loadLastInfoUI(data: BidsRes) {
            cancelTimer()
}
```

When call **presenter.getLastInfo(token, auctionId)** api, receive this api data with **loadLastInfoUI**.

```
    private fun cancelTimer() {
        try {
            Log.e("BidsLog", "Cancel")
            countDownTimer.cancel()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

**My logcat :**

```
2020-08-04 12:28:07.646 30602-30602/com.app.android E/BidsLog: Cancel
2020-08-04 12:28:08.642 30602-30602/com.app.android E/BidsLog: Cancel
2020-08-04 12:28:09.641 30602-30602/com.app.android E/BidsLog: Cancel
2020-08-04 12:28:10.643 30602-30602/com.app.android E/BidsLog: Cancel
2020-08-04 12:28:11.655 30602-30602/com.app.android E/BidsLog: Cancel
2020-08-04 12:28:12.645 30602-30602/com.app.android E/BidsLog: Cancel
```

Why after call cancel log from `cancelTimer` method, again call this method again and not cancel this timer?

How can i cancel it and just once show this log message ?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Do you still face a problem with timer?

Comment: 'WHY NOT ANY PEOPLE HELP ME?' Maybe its because you don't respond to others answers...

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is being cancelled. Add log to `onTick` method, then call cancel and check if logs from `onTick` are not being printed anymore to ensure that your timer was cancelled.
The reason you see `"BidsLog: Cancel"` is because cancelling your timer does not cancel logging.